# Why will my code sometimes not work as expected?

Tags: java

The exercise is:

> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below N.

I have used BigInteger so I can handle big numbers. I pass the first test case, but by the submission I only pass one of the six test cases. So there is a problem with my code, but I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can someone help me? Thank you.

This is what I have got:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
     Solution solution = new Solution();
     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        long input = scanner.nextLong();
        BigInteger sums = new BigInteger("0");
        sums = sums.add(solution.calculateSum(input));              
        if (sums.signum() == 1){
            System.out.println(sums);
        }
     }
}

private BigInteger calculateSum(long input){
   input--;
   long totalElements = 0;
   BigInteger sums = new BigInteger("0");
   if (input >= 3){
       totalElements = input/3;
       sums = sums.add(BigInteger.valueOf((totalElements * (3 + totalElements *3))/2));
   }
   if (input >= 5){
       totalElements = input/5;
       sums = sums.add(BigInteger.valueOf((totalElements * (5 + totalElements *5))/2));
   }
   if (input >= 15){
       totalElements = input/15;
       sums = sums.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf((totalElements * (15 + totalElements *15))/2));
   }
   return sums;
}}
```

Comment: Do you mean [Problem 1 - Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1)? You won't need to sum all answers from each test cases.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes I mean Problem 1. In my code, I dont sum all test cases, or have I done something wrong?

Comment: You need to look up the modulus function if (%)  N % 3 == 0, N % 5 == 0.

Comment: @user3505506 Yes, you don't sum answers for separate test cases. I misunderstood.

Comment: you are right, but I want constant time. So I am using the arithmatic progression formula.

Comment: There are only 2 test cases in the site. What is the constraint for the test cases? Are you sure that won't cause overflow?

Comment: I am learning at Hackerrank.com. Here is a [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler001). They test 3 test cases. I pass them. When I go to the submission of my code. I can't pass the final test cases.

Comment: You said project euler  in original statements, and afaik it had no premise for 'how' you get your results - seeing as you've later said its actually different attempts to get the results my comments above are moot. Refer to MikeCAT below

Comment: VeenarM sorry for the confusing. I thought there was no difference, but I was wrong. Everyone thanks for the help, I really appreciate it. The next time I will be more clear.

Comment: Why are you using BigInteger when your calculations are using longs? i.e. you are assuming your result fit into a `long` so using a BigInteger is redundant.

Comment: @PeterLawrey BigInteger is bigger than long. The input is in long and if I sum everything, I use a BigInteger, because there is a chance that the sum not fit in a long.

Comment: @user3505506 in that case you need to use `BigInteger` and not `long` for your calculation.

Comment: For the input is a long enough, it's big enough to hold the input. But if your input is a high number. The sum will be the sum of all high numbers. And that can't fit in a long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your routine to deal with test cases is completely wrong. Read the statement and follow that.

Also you won't need the addition and sign check.

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Solution solution = new Solution();
    int size = scanner.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        long input = scanner.nextLong();
        BigInteger sums = solution.calculateSum(input);
        System.out.println(sums);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it a good idea to post answers concerning `ProjectEuler` ?

Comment: Thank you very much :). It works. You are my hero. Can you give me more information what I did wrong?

Comment: I see what I did wrong. I thought that everytime there are 3 inputs, apparently the inputs are different.

Comment: @YassinHajaj I think there is no ProjectEuler tag.

Comment: @YassinHajaj Yes you are right, but the problem that I had was that I don't  know how to implement the input from Hackerrank in my code correctly. My algortihm for solving the problem was correct. And I think that I had solved the problem at my own. Afterwards was my question Java oriented and not on solving the problem.